# Finding Crystal Hearts in Terraria

Tags: terraria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve my chances to find Hearts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24376/how-can-i-improve-my-chances-to-find-hearts)

Is there a strategy I can use to increase my chances of finding crystal hearts? Right I i am just exploring caves, but have only found one so far.

im still in early game, iron armor, tools and weapons.

Is there anything i can do? or just keep exploring?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24376/how-can-i-improve-my-chances-to-find-hearts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short of downloading a Map Viewer to determine where the closest Crystal Hearts are, there's no easy way forward. Depending on how deep you explore and variance in luck, you can get streaks of crystal heart caverns and chests galore, or no interesting items sans torch pots.

That said, you definitely should keep exploring caves (and mining into new caves from existing caves wherever possible / you can find them). While exploring will obviously help your survival when you find new crystal hearts, it will also give you a chance to find silver and gold ore. Your priority should be a gold pickaxe (to mine Meteorite), but after that feel free to throw all your excess silver and gold into defensive equipment.

Better gear is *like* getting Crystal Hearts, because it increases the number of hits you take (though obviously your HP remains the same). As to finding Silver and Gold, Floating Islands tend to be full of them. Consider building a skybridge of some sort to find islands, but if you do, mind the Harpeys (typo intentional).

Answer (score 1):

Just keep exploring, you'll come across them sooner or later.  When you can clear the dungeon, in a large map Ive found upwards ten just exploring that dungeon alone although it will be a while before you can clear skeletron.

Max health is 400, just takes a while to get there :)

Comment: And once you're there, they can't take it away from you!